# Find the Maclaurin series of $f(x) = x^7\sin(4x^3)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Find the Maclaurin series of $f(x) = x^7\sin(4x^3)$

Can you folks show me some different ways to do this one? Is the best way to do it just to start taking derivatives of $f(x)$, plugging in zero and using the general formula? I keep getting this wrong. The answer is supposed to be:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n4^{2n+1}x^7x^{6n+3}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Comment: put $4x^3$ into the taylor series of sin(x) and multiply everything by $x^7$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's **not** the best way. The best way is\begin{align}x^7\sin(4x^3)&=x^7\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(4x^3)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=x^7\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n4^{2n+1}x^{6n+3}}{(2n+1)!}\\&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n4^{2n+1}x^{6n+10}}{(2n+1)!}.\end{align}